# How to perform Do Calculation work flow in SharePoint2010 Designer

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How can I do a simple arithmetic multiplication in sharepoint workflow 2010 for a list? could anyone please provide me a good example?

I have tried to create an a workflow for a list,which I saved and published; but it is giving error while running? I dont know, what is this error and how to find and fix this error?

I have a list named "List_Proj_Calc",  two columns "No.days" and "Hours". I want to multiply this colums values and display to next column "Total Hours"

I have confusion on how to put values on "look up for number" dialog to get this result, somebody please help me.

Steps I followed:

1.Added Do calculation in step1 template.

2.Clicked the calculate item link and opened the Look Up dialog window.

3.Selected the "Data source" as my list name eg: List_Proj_Calc.

4.Selected the "Field From Source" as List field name as "No.days".

5.In find list option I gave field No.days and value I gave some number

6.Next I Selected "Multiplied by" option

7.Selected other look up dialog for multiply.

8.repeated the same steps for data source and Filed name selection

9.Gave list column name "Hours" as filed name to multiply

10.Saved and published.

But error!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you create a list workflow on list List_Proj_Calc.

Therefore:
3 - In "Data source", instead of List_Proj_Calc select "Current Item" and in
4 - "Field from Source" select "No.days"
5 - in "Output to" create a new variable, let's say VarTotalHours
6 - set your total column with a value from the variable 
6.1. select "set field in Current Item"
6.2. in "field" select "Total Hours"
6.3. in "value" open a dialog and 
6.3.1. in "Data source" select "Workflow Variables and Parameters"
6.3.2. in "Field from source" select "Variable: VarTotalHours"

The final workflow should look like this:

[image: do calculations workflow]

Alternatively, you can get the same effect with no workflow (and I recommend this solution).
Create a calculated field "Total Hours" with a formula:

```
=[No.days]*[Hours]
```